# Neo4j Configuration

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4j server.  I'm running into an issue where the loads are relatively low.  However, the response times are quite high.  I think that the number of threads servicing requests is simply too small.  Is there a way to adjust the size of the thread pool for servicing HTTP requests.  Is that possible?

Comment: Did you create any logs to measure performance so you know when you leave the client and what actually is time consuming? I once had a problem with a REST Client implementation which took 2 seconds to create a request ... Logging all the requests we finally found that there is not a server performance leak, but a client side problem ...
Note that you can also "profile" The query with `profile` or `explain`.

Answer (score 6):

It's a common misconception that more threads equals more performance. In reality it's often the other way around -- more threads equals lesser performance. I don't know how your graph or requests look though so it may not apply in your case.

But you can control that pool size with the property:

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.maxthreads
```

in conf/neo4j-server.properties

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that it often takes some experimentation to find the sweet spot.  However, at the moment, I think incoming requests are being blocked waiting for a thread to open up to serve the requests.  Do you know if these setting are document anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any work to optimize your queries?   Added indexes, etc.?

Are you on the latest release (2.2.1)?   I found that the performance enhancements in this newest release as they relate to my application to be significant.

Answer (score 0):

It's very important to profile your queries in neo4j as a starting point, especially if you are finding that some queries are getting a slow response while others do not.  Changes in the query structure can make a huge difference in performance.  If you are new to neo4j I suggest you look at this post from Wes Freeman explaining why some queries are slow and what you can do about it:
[Pragmatic Cypher Optimization](http://wes.skeweredrook.com/pragmatic-cypher-optimization-2-0-m06/)